# Angular JS controller doesn't work with routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, salesforce, angular-routing, angular-controller

I’m working with Angular JS 1.3, I have problem with `ngRoute`, in the code below
angular redirects to `"apex/" + pathTemplate + "_product"` (the page works in Salesforce container) but control doesn’t return to controller `homeController`.

```
  .when(pathComm + ':categoryCode/:productCode', {
        templateUrl: function () {
            return "apex/" + pathTemplate + "_product"
        },
        controller: "homeController"
    })
```

Instead with snippet code following when the path is with only one path variable it works:

```
 .when(pathComm + ':productCode', {
        templateUrl: function () {
            return "apex/" + pathTemplate + "_product"
        },
        controller: "homeController"
    })
```

Comment: The routing code looks okay. Just check whether you added controller to application module:
     `OrdersController.$inject=['$scope', '$routeParams'];`  
     `angular.module('yourApp')
        .controller('yourController', yourController);`

Comment: The controller is just added to application module.

Answer (score 0):

In html you have to pass parameter parameter with url like this:

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary" ng-href="#/student/{{row._id}}/studentName/{{studentName}}">Edit</a>
```

After that bind controller with url which contain parameters.Like:

```
.when('/student/:id/studentName/:surName', {                            
    templateUrl: 'templates/student/addForm.html',
    controller: 'YourController'
});
```

And Catch parameter in controller like this:

```
 $http.get('/student/'+$routeParams.id +'/studentName/'+ $routeParams.surName).success(function (response) {
 alert(response);
 $scope.studentList = response;
 $scope.id = response['_id'];});
```